# SSL/TLS Private Key chain for multi environment support

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

Can i create an SSL/TLS private key file that contains multiple private keys by chaining them one after another?

So the chain will look something like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.
.
9TvrBymCYT1AYhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxABzg6jGPUo2oU6vl
cqKzgV8XpRqdKtzrI/2Bskxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
7ptgeHcEOtNhqmXgO+utKDrzG0ekpW3W+eCRBe6ncxGVIrk/2fglov9sWwolvVSr
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.
.
9TvrBymCYT1AYhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxABzg6jGPUo2oU6vl
cqKzgV8XpRqdKtzrI/2Bskxxxffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffx
7ptgeHcEOtNhqmXgO+utKDrzG0ekpW3W+eCRBe6ncxGVIrk/2fglov9sWwolvVSr
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am trying to build an nginx docker image that i can use for all environment (DEV, QA, UAT). And trying to avoid build image for very environment. Below is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:1.15.0-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY certs/nginxbundle-dev.crt /etc/ssl/nginx.crt
COPY certs/private_key_bundle.key /etc/ssl/nginx.key
```

Below is the nginx conf.

```
upstream backendservice {
  server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}

server {
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://backendservice;
    }

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.xyz.com;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx.key;
}
```

I think i can add the SSL/TLS Certs for all the 3 environments into the cert bundle `/etc/ssl/nginx.crt`. But i am not sure if similiar chaining can be done for the `private key`. I have 3 different private keys for all the 3 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.
Chaining certificates together in a file means that it should provide the first one as leaf certificate and the other ones as chain certificates, i.e. it will not pick only the certificates for the specific host from the file. Similar it will expect that the key file has only the private key matching the leaf certificate in it as the first entry. It will ignore any other entries in the file.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. I guess the other way to remove the ssl certs from the build and mount them from the file system.